# When to use Poisson distribution?

Tags: distributions, self-study, normal-distribution, poisson-distribution

I'm slightly confused with when I should use a Poisson distribution.

If I have a case where:

- I have the sample mean of the number of events happening in a particular day (say it is 1.27).
- Five days are randomly selected from a sample.

Can I use the Poisson process to find the probability that the sample mean now is more than 0.3?

Comment: I'm not completely sure I understand your description, but it sounds like you're trying to construct some kind of interval for a Poisson mean for some unobserved time period based on a sample for some other time period. Is that correct?

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reverts Glen. I'm not quite sure if Poisson is the game here. What i have on hand is a probability distribution of the number of events happening on a particular day - from which I've worked out the mean. What i want to find out is the probability that this mean is going to be more than 0.3 if 4 days are randomly selected from a sample. Is the sample size important?

Comment: Oh, I think I see. You've been *given* some probability distribution for a random variable representing the number of events per day. You computed the mean of that distribution (a population mean). Then you start talking about a *sample* mean over several days of observations. Is that it? (There are several strange things about your wording that make it especially confusing.)

Comment: Spot on Glen! You're really brilliant. Yeps. Thats what Im trying to self learn and solve

Comment: Then yes, you should be able to work out that probability. A big hint: convert the event in terms of the sample mean to a sum ($\frac{T}{n}>k$ is the same as $T>kn$). [Take care with the distinction between 'greater than' and 'greater than or equal to'; make sure you have the right one]

Comment: I will say that there's no hint in the little information you give that the Poisson comes into this at all. A little more detail might clarify that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I understand the Poisson distribution: the distribution is used to describe events happening over a given range(i.e. a time period)

For the PDF distribution you can use it for things like the probabilities for:

- Number of mutation in DNA strands per unit of time.
- N peaks in stock in a over a given period of time

For the CDF distribution you can use it for the probabilities of:

- 3 or less robberies in a given length of time.